# jQuery to add all the values in a HTML table column

Tags: jquery, html

Can somebody help me out to troubleshoot this code? I am looking to add all the values of a HTML table column using JQuery. Please see below example I can not get this functional.

The first table is just a normal table holding the data, the second table should be filled dynamically with jQuery adding up the columns.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" SRC="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">  

 //these will hold the totals
 var ages = 0;
 var weights = 0;
 var benchpresses = 0;

 //reference the rows you want to add
 //this will not include the header row
 var rows = $("#data tr:gt(0)");
 rows.children("td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
 //each time we add the cell to the total
 ages += parseInt($(this).html());
 });
 rows.children("td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
 weights += parseInt($(this).html());
 });
 rows.children("td:nth-child(4)").each(function() {
 benchpresses += parseInt($(this).html());
 });

 //then output them to the elements
 $("#ages").html(ages);
 $("#weights").html(weights);
 $("#benchpresses").html(benchpresses);

 </script>
 </head>
 <TABLE class=custom id=data>
 <TBODY>
 <TR>
  <TH>name</TH>
  <TH>age</TH>
  <TH>weight</TH>
  <TH>benchpress</TH>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>stan</TD>
  <TD>27</TD>
  <TD>177</TD>
  <TD>325</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>rj</TD>
  <TD>30</TD>
  <TD>135</TD>
  <TD>95</TD>
 </TR>
<TR>
  <TD>jose</TD>
  <TD>29</TD>
  <TD>230</TD>
  <TD>375</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
<BR>
<TABLE class=custom>
<TBODY>
<TR>
  <TH>ages</TH>
  <TH>weights</TH>
  <TH>benchpresses</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD id=ages>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD id=weights>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD id=benchpresses>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</html>
```

Comment: While it doesn't seem to be affecting your code, `parseInt($(this).html());` should be `parseInt($(this).text(),10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the code to sum the columns will execute before the columns/tables/data exist.  Several ways to fix, easiest is to move the `<script>` block in your example to after the table definition.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" SRC="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>

 </head>
 <TABLE class=custom id=data>
 <TBODY>
 <TR>
  <TH>name</TH>
  <TH>age</TH>
  <TH>weight</TH>
  <TH>benchpress</TH>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>stan</TD>
  <TD>27</TD>
  <TD>177</TD>
  <TD>325</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>rj</TD>
  <TD>30</TD>
  <TD>135</TD>
  <TD>95</TD>
 </TR>
<TR>
  <TD>jose</TD>
  <TD>29</TD>
  <TD>230</TD>
  <TD>375</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
<BR>
<TABLE class=custom>
<TBODY>
<TR>
  <TH>ages</TH>
  <TH>weights</TH>
  <TH>benchpresses</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD id=ages>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD id=weights>&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD id=benchpresses>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
 <script type="text/javascript">  

 //these will hold the totals
 var ages = 0;
 var weights = 0;
 var benchpresses = 0;

 //reference the rows you want to add
 //this will not include the header row
 var rows = $("#data tr:gt(0)");
 rows.children("td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
 //each time we add the cell to the total
 ages += parseInt($(this).html());
 });
 rows.children("td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
 weights += parseInt($(this).html());
 });
 rows.children("td:nth-child(4)").each(function() {
 benchpresses += parseInt($(this).html());
 });

 //then output them to the elements
 $("#ages").html(ages);
 $("#weights").html(weights);
 $("#benchpresses").html(benchpresses);

 </script>
</html>
```